# Can I make GitHub render a .qmd (quarto) file instead of showing the raw text?

Tags: github, render, quarto

Can I force GitHub to show the rendered version of a `.qmd` file when I open it? This way, diffs would be made easier for developers and users would be able to view both the input and output of each cell.